# Expose the same metric but with different labels

Tags: timestamp, time-series, prometheus

[Prometheus] Hello!
I intend to expose to Prometheus the same metric but with different labels, for example:

```
m2{device="A"} 25 1513076400000
m2{device="B"} 20 1513075500000
m2{device="C"} 18 1513078680000
```

These three elements refer to the same timeserie or 3 different timeseries? And why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [prometheus data model intro](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/):

> Every time series is uniquely identified by its metric name and a set
>   of key-value pairs, also known as labels.

So your three elements are three separate time series. The reason this is better than one big string (eg: `m2_device_B`) is that labels make manipulation of related metrics much simpler (eg: `sum by label`).